Calculate RERI for categorical variables?
I want to examine the interaction between two variables, one is continuous (mean-centered) and one is categorical (with three levels). I will use the negative binomial regression. I searched many papers but I'm not sure about the RERI for this. Usually if the variable is binary, it's easy, just b11 - b10 - b01 + 1. But since I have three levels in one variable, how to calcualte the RERI?

What is a RERI, and how is the [tag:epidemiology] tag relevant?

@StephanKolassa   RERI: the relative excessive risk due to interaction. This is an epi concept and analysis.

In the context of categorical variables with more than two levels, there will be more than one relative excessive risk due to interaction (RERI) or interaction contrast ratio to report. We can see this from the corresponding formula. Note that the RERI is defined as
$$RERI = RR_{11} - RR_{10} - RR_{01} + 1$$
for a binary exposure, where $A$ is our exposure, $M$ is the modifier, $Y$ is the outcome, and
$$ RR_{am} = \frac{\Pr(Y=1 \mid A=a, M=m)}{\Pr(Y=1 \mid A=0, M=0)} $$
Now consider if $A$ could take values of $0,1,2$ and our modifier is still binary. With $A=0$ as the referent, we have two RERI
$$ RERI_{1} = RR_{11} - RR_{10} - RR_{01} + 1 $$
and
$$ RERI_{2} = RR_{21} - RR_{20} - RR_{01} + 1 $$
If you instead had a categorical modifier, we would instead have
$$ RERI_{1} = RR_{11} - RR_{10} - RR_{01} + 1 $$
and
$$ RERI_{2} = RR_{12} - RR_{10} - RR_{02} + 1 $$
The key is to pay attention to the underlying quantities you are estimating. Then you can combine them according to the RERI formula.
When you have a continuous modifier (or exposure), the RERI is not straightforward (to my knowledge). Since it sounds like you are in that scenario, you might want to consider looking into marginal structural models (MSMs). MSMs make looking at modification by categorical or continuous variables easier.

Thank you so much! Yes my modifier would be the categorical one. This is so helpful!!
